# skel.js Framework / HTML5UP Template CSS issues

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, skel

I'm new to the skel.js framework and I'm having some issues.

I downloaded a template from HTML5UP.net (Zerofour theme) and I have modified it all for my site however the CSS doesn't show up properly on my *no-sidebar* & *left-sidebar* pages.

I have an include with the follwing links (identical to their templates):

```
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800"         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://www.**********.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.**********.com/js/jquery.dropotron.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.**********.com/js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.**********.com/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.**********.com/js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>

    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.*********.com/css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.*********.com/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.*********.com/css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>
```

If I bypass the noscript the webpage appears as it should but loses ALL mobile and flowable capabilites.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

**Addon**: If I move my pages to the root directory and update the links then the CSS works but in their child directories only the basic layout works.

```
    <?php
    define(currentDIR,'../');
    include (currentDIR.'includes/_functions.php');
    ?>
    <html>
<head>
    <?php include(currentDIR.'includes/_metalinks.php'); ?> //This is where the code above is stored
</head>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also came across this issue while using an HTML5up template with Django. If you are using a different directory configuration for your static files, you must specify this in either the init.js or config.js file (the exact file depends on which template you are using and how recently it has been updated). For me, I had to modify the following skelJS prefix in the init.js file:

```
    var helios_settings = {
        // other settings here

        skelJS: {prefix: '/static/css/style',

        // other settings here
        }
```

Basically, this directory prefix needs to match wherever you have your static files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-noscript.css" />
```

Comment: There is no such file in the template. However, there is the skel-noscript.css linked in the noscript.

Comment: Could you post the parts of the css that you have modified ?

Comment: See edit. It's not an issue with the CSS itself but the structure or linking to it. ...I think

Comment: SOLVED! I changed the prefix in the config.js ...will post answer when StackOverflow allows (low rep).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and was able to fix it by modifying the config.js file to use the absolute path as follows:

```
prefix: '/css/style',
```

Now files in both the root and other directories maintain the styling throughout.