# CSS Not Loading From Correct Folder Due to JS

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a website from a template I downloaded. I created a new folder in the root directory where I want to put some webpages. There are also folders in the root directory for the js and css.

Example Root

```
-css
---style.css
-js
---skel.min.js
-folder
---page1.html
---page2.html
```

Everything works right on page1.html when I preview it in Dreamweaver (the links stylesheet links have been updated to the correct folder). However, when I preview it in Chrome the style sheet is not being accessed correctly. It wants to pull from `folder/css/style.css`, which doesn't exist.

Using the Inspect Console on Chrome. It's telling me that something in the js (skel.min.js) is trying to pull from the nonexistent css folder.

Can anyone offer me any help or suggestions?

Here is the snippet of code that appears to be working incorrectly.

```js
registerLocation: function(e, t) {
            var n = "_skel_attach",
                r = "appendChild";
            e == "head" ? t[n] = function(e) {
                this === _.me.parentNode ? this.insertBefore(e, _.me) : this[r](e)
            } : t[n] = function(e) {
                this[r](e)
            }, _.locations[e] = t
        },
```

And here also is the link to the webpage in case you need more information: http://exq-leadership.com/podcasts/episode01.html

Answer (score 1):

Replace your relative path with an absolute path in your  tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

While I am not familiar with skel, it seems it is removing the relative path part `../` of the styles.

Comment: I tried that before and just now and that didn't have any effect on it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think of searching around for help with the actual skel.min.js. I was just searching with the code snippet which wasn't working. I did some searching around for the actual js file and found that I had to change the prefix in the init.js file to

```js
prefix: '/css/style',
```

This is what helped me: [skel.js Framework / HTML5UP Template CSS issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520865/skel-js-framework-html5up-template-css-issues)

Everything works now.

Thank you for the inspiration, Antony!